# Order by date, if name not found order by time

Tags: sql, date

Is it possible to order by date, and if date is not specified to order by time, and if time is bigger than date then it will be first on the list.
For example we got table -

```
id    date         time          name

1    18.10.2011    18.10.2011    number    
2    ---------     19.10.2011    number2    
3    ---------     18.10.2011    number3
```

And it should order something like this -

```
1    number2
2    number
3    number3
```

All data is saved in database in `time()` format, so iif the time and date is equal, it will look at clock. Hope you understood me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can attempt to use `ORDER BY CASE`.  This is untested, but should set you on the right track:

```
ORDER BY CASE
  WHEN date IS NOT NULL AND time < date THEN date
  WHEN time > date OR date IS NULL THEN time
  ELSE time
END
```

Actually, the `ELSE time` is probably unnecessary here. The first two cases should cover it.

Comment: Hmm is it possible to do something like this - i got time in this format - time() + (90 * 24 * 60 * 60) inserted in database, so i will need to display it as time() - (90 * 24 * 60 * 60) to get insert date (cause time displays date when row will be removed).
Y2OK

Comment: What data types are your columns? Are they actual `DATETIME` and `TIME` types, or ints representing UNIX timestamps?

Comment: Hello the tables are just varchar.

Comment: @Y2ok: How are the times being represented if they are stored as varchars? (and who thought it was a good idea to store date and time fields as varchars?)

Comment: hmm they are represented as date();

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
select id, date, time, name
from MyTable
order by greatest(time,coalesce(date,time))
```

(Some of these column names are likely to be reserved words - I hope this is a simplified example!)